# Multiple selection of worksheets into one workbook copy paste of content into one main sheet

Tags: vba, excel

What i am trying here  to achieve if multiple selection of excel files into my workbook and copy paste the content into the sheet called "Source". But although the first file i import works correctly the second one does not paste after my last used row. What is wrong with it?

```
Sub Import()

'Clear previous Front Page sheet & error report information
Sheets("Source").Cells.clearcontents
Sheets("Source").Cells.ClearFormats

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'Seek the file to be imported

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set wbb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh = wbb.Worksheets("Source")

With fd
    .Title = "Please select the early correction file to be imported"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    Err.Clear
    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If MsgBox("Files selected, continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    If FileChosen = -1 Then
        For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            file = fd.SelectedItems(i)
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=file, ReadOnly:=True
            If file = "" Then Exit Sub
            filesheet = "Template"
            Sheets(filesheet).Cells.COPY
            LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets("Source").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            'Workbooks(file).Close savechanges:=False
        Next i
    End If
End With

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

If MsgBox("ERROR: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Do you want to Continue...?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Error") = vbYes Then
    Resume Next
End If
```

Comment: You need to be careful when referencing `Sheets` especially when multiple workbooks are open. Make sure you always specify the `Workbook` as well to ensure you are referring to the correct location. For example, you've used `Set sh = wbb.Worksheets("Source")` so any references to `Sheets("Source")` can be replaced with `sh`. Also, your `Sheets(filesheet).Cells.Copy` should be changed to `Workbooks(file).Sheets(filesheet).Cells.Copy`

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me

```
Sub Import()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Set wbb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wbb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With fd
        .Title = "Please select the early correction file to be imported"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        Err.Clear
        FileChosen = fd.Show
        If MsgBox("Files selected, continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

        For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            file = fd.SelectedItems(i)
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=file, ReadOnly:=True
            If file = "" Then Exit Sub
            filesheet = "Sheet1"
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(filesheet).UsedRange.Copy
            LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "current book " & i
        Next i
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I didnt include everything i was just getting to the "heart of it." I also changed the sheets names to match my test scenario. You had some sheet referencing issues, which is why it probably failed. When working with multiple workbooks at the same time its easy to confuse the compiler. Fully referencing/qualifying them is a good habit to get into.

Another thing that is not a good habit is Copy/Pasting. This could easily be done in various ways that isnt so overhead taxing. Saying stuff similar to:

```
 Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
```

Is INF better. With what youre doing I'd probably dump everything into an array first then dump to sheet. Either way, its a better practice.

Comment: i ll try it thanks. also my last line that i have as a comment does not work to close the open workbook so i dont left many of them open. Any ideas?

Comment: No it does not work for me. the second file i am trying to copy does not copy at all.

Comment: @Irene see my edited post. Just saying "ActiveWorkBook.Close does the trick! As far as it not working for you, I cant say why it isnt. You may need to review your sheet references.

Comment: @Irene I foudn the issue, you IF FileChosen = -1 criteria was jacking everythig up. I even inserted code to tell me what the dumped values were, which is how I discovered the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it still does not paste the second file. it s driving me crazy

Comment: @Irene im not sure what youve got going on but my code as is did paste all my sample workbooks i used. When i get home Ill try and review again

Answer (score 0):

There was a little error with the LastRow method.  It should work now, at least it does for me.

```
Sub Import()
Dim fnMine
Dim firsTime As Boolean
'Clear previous Front Page sheet & error report information
Sheets("Source").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Source").Cells.ClearFormats

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
'Seek the file to be imported

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set wbb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh = wbb.Worksheets("Source")
firsTime = True

With fd
    .Title = "Please select the early correction file to be imported"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    Err.Clear
    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If MsgBox("Files selected, continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    If FileChosen = -1 Then
        For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            file = fd.SelectedItems(i)
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=file, ReadOnly:=True
            fnMine = Split(file, "\")
            fnMine = fnMine(UBound(fnMine))
            If file = "" Then Exit Sub
            filesheet = "Template"
            Sheets(filesheet).Select
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
            Selection.Copy
            If firsTime = True Then
                LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                firsTime = False
            Else
                LastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If

            wbb.Activate
             Sheets("Source").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Workbooks(fnMine).Close savechanges:=False
        Next i
    End If
End With


Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

If MsgBox("ERROR: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Do you want to Continue...?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Error") = vbYes Then
    Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping out but it s not working still. There seems to be a problem with my second file as it does not paste it. Does it work for you all the way?

Comment: There was a small problem with the LastRow method.  LastRow gives you row 1 if row 1 is empty or not.  I changed the answer above to account for that.  Try it again.

Comment: That wouldn't necessarily be your problem though.  What are your full path and filenames?  Maybe there is a problem with the path or filename.  This code works well for me.  I'm using test1.xlsx, test2.xlsx, and test3.xlsx for my test files and the path is in C:\MyDocuments\