# Use file picker to find specific documents then copy and paste

Tags: vba, search, filepicker

After I find the file paths I want to be able to copy data from six to seven of the workbooks selected and then paste them all into the active file. Any help getting me started from here would be great.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
```

Comment: review this, i think this is what youre after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848830/multiple-selection-of-worksheets-into-one-workbook-copy-paste-of-content-into-on/43849280#43849280

Comment: What have you tried from there? Since you have your `wb`, just copy the data and paste to your active file. Note: You should create a variable for your ActiveFile at the start, so you can refer to that when copying. I.e. `Dim myData as Workbook // Dim dataWS as Worksheet`, then later you could do say `wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy dataWS.Range("A1:A10")`...

Comment: I want to re write it so once you search/find the correct folder it does several different commands based upon key words in the name of the file. For example if the name contains "Labortotal" then copy and paste x to the current worksheet, then if the name contains "equipmenttotal.xslm" then paste y accordingly and so forth. Thanks!